# How to make fixed-rate dynamic in XML based task schedulers?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduled ref="testBean" method="testMethod" fixed-rate="1000"/>      

</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

In the above snippet, I want to pass fixed-rate as variable fetched from the config file. How can I do that?

P.S. I don't want to move to the annotation-based scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

After going through various articles and documentation I found a way to achieve the same. So sharing the same.

I created a configuration bean of a loader class. Loader class is responsbile to fetch the configs (either from file or any configuration management tool) and set in the system properties.

```
<bean id="configuration" class="com.test.config.loader">
</bean>
```

Say one the property is like
database:mysql

It can be accessed like

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>

<task:scheduled ref="testBean" method="testMethod" fixed-rate="#{configuration['database']}"/>      

</task:scheduled-tasks>
```